# MYSQL Left Join returning all rows that match the first character

Tags: mysql, left-join

I've got a simple left join in a MYSQL environment.

```
SELECT *
FROM (`holiday`)
LEFT JOIN `member` ON `member`.`memberId` = `holiday`.`memberId`
ORDER BY `holiday`.`begin_date` ASC
```

However instead of returning only exact matches it is returning any records where the member.memberId has the holiday.memberId in the first character.

Results:

```
holidayId holiday.memberId member.memberId
9         1                1
9         1A65152F         1
10        1                1
10        1A65152F         1
```

How do I get it to just return the exact matches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The field `holiday.memberId`is a STRING, while `member.memberId` is a INTEGER, so MySQL automatically casts the string to a Number (e.g. "123ABC" will be converted to 123).

You could try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (`holiday`)
LEFT JOIN `member` ON `member`.`memberId` = BINARY `holiday`.`memberId`
ORDER BY `holiday`.`begin_date` ASC
```

Using BINARY it will force a binary comparison, disabling the automatic cast.

Or you should convert both fields to string.

Comment: Think it is a typo (and doesn't affect your example code being correct), but with an integer and a string MySQL will compare as a float I think. Hence the string is converted to a number, which in this case means dropping everything including and after the first non numeric character.

Comment: @Kickstart thanks for the comment, yes there was a typo, now it should be fixed :) I am not sure if the string will be converted to an integer or to a float, i have to check for this! tnx